# D3.js Cross Table

Tags: d3.js

I'm looking for an example of how to create a Cross Table using D3. I have searched over the Internet but I can't found anything like that. I need to create a migration matrix as show bellow:

[image]

Any idea would be appreciated. Thanks,

Marcio

Comment: Actually you don't need SVG/D3 to do this, it can be done with `<div>`s

Comment: Thanks @MichaelRovinsky, but I would need to use D3 for data integration in Tibco Spotfire.

Comment: Basically it's just `<rect>`s and `<text>`s... So rendering with D3 should be quite simple. Can you post your data sample?

Comment: https://www.d3-graph-gallery.com/graph/heatmap_basic.html